# Integrate ITK (Insight Toolkit) into own project

Tags: c++, image-processing, integration, cmake, itk

i am having problems integrating ITK - Insight Toolkit into another image processing pipeline. ITK itself is a medical image processing toolkit and uses cmake as build system. My image pipeline project uses cmake as well. According to the user manual of ITK it is favorable to use the "UseITK.cmake" file in the build (out of source) directory of ITK. You can do that by adding the following lines the CMakeList.txt of your own project.

```
# 'SET(ITK_DIR ...)' if 'FIND_PACKAGE(ITK REQUIRED)' fails
FIND_PACKAGE(ITK REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${ITK_USE_FILE})
```

My problem is, this approach points to the current installtion of ITK, but i have to integrate itk completly into my project, without dependencies outside my project.
Is there a build option in the cmake build system of itk, which dumps/delivers all the header and lib files into a build directory, so i can place them into my project on my own.
I have a lib and header include structure i do not want to break. I already tried to to manually copy the lib and header files into my project but it didn't work out.

I am new to itk and cmake so this question might sound vague. I hope you guys can help me anyway.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

zhengtonic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you're still having the problem, but here's an easy way:

Build the ITK project, and then "make install" (or build the INSTALL.vcproj project in VS), and it will write to a directory you pass as CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX while configuring your project. This directory will contain /bin, /lib and /include. You can import those into your project directly.

Comment: Excuse me Shash but how to pass CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to my project configuration

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/wher/ever

Or, edit CMakeCache.txt in the build dir, search for CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and change it

Comment: I've had a similar/identical question and this answer helped me, too. Thx shash. I've placed a more extensive description to my question. --> [link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285254/llinking-itk-insight-toolkit-to-c-vs2008-solution-without-using-cmake)

Answer (score 2):

Using CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to point to you base directory is the best solution.

When you issue "make install" all the headers/configurationfiles/libraries will be copied over.

Comment: i dont understand what is the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and how to use it, excuse me i'm a bigenner with itk

Comment: Hey Sara, sorry for the really late reply, but you can find CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX inside CMakeCache.txt in the build directory, after you run cmake. If you're using the CMake GUI, you can just search for that parameter and change it.

Answer (score 1):

C:/Program Files (x86)/ITK is value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for ITK and set automatically.