# Llinking ITK (Insight Toolkit) to C++ VS2008 solution without using CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, itk

#### *Question*

**Is there an easy, straight forward way of including the ITK libraries into my project (VS2008 solution) *without* using CMake?**

#### *Background*

I have just started looking into ITK this week. So far I successfully compiled ITK & VTK and got the WikiExamples to compile (and run) as well. My next goal is to include any ITK functionality into my own project. I have no experiences with CMake except the use of it during the documented installation process.

My own project codebase is in itself a rather complicated, SDK environment in rather large, complex VS2008 solution to which I only want to add a bit of ITK functionality. As I have built ITK already, can I simply set includes to the .h files and add the lib directories to the linker?

Is there a *good* way to do this, as the .h files are spread over the whole ITK code tree?

I've realized that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255559/integrate-itk-insight-toolkit-into-own-project) is similar, but the given answer was too cryptic for me, sorry.

*Edit:* After a 2nd and 3rd read, it actually wasn't. It led to my answer below.

Comment: The best way (and only officially supported method) to use any opensource Kitware software (even with Visual Studio) is to use CMake to generate your Visual Studio project for your application. This will save you loads of pain dealing with compiler and linker settings unless you have a very deep understanding of the Visual Studio compiler and linker settings.

Comment: Hi, I've used CMake to build ITK and VTK, I just didn't know how to then proceed to use them in my project which I don't want to use CMake for. However, after 2nd read of the alternative question (link above), I've realized that there is an "Install" project in the solution which is not automatically build in ALL_BUILD, but - if build - copies all the files into one location (C:\Program Files (x86)\itk) for easy link-up, and that this folder can be specified using CMake and the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable when configuring the ITK project....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When configuring ITK with CMake (or cmake-gui) one can set the variable **CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX** to a destination for all output. The default value is *C:/Programm Files (x84)/itk*

[image: CMAKE-GUI setting up ITK build]

After **Configure** and **Generate** have been performed successfully, the solution file (*ITK.sln*) has been created in the given "Where to build the binaries" directory and can be opened in Visual Studi0 2008. The solution has the default project **ALL_BUILD** which builds the solution, but it also has a **INSTALL** project which is skipped by default.

[image: VS 2008 solution]

Building this solution (after ALL_BUILD) copies all required lib, .h, .dll etc. files into the path specified before.

[image: VS 2008 output after building INSTALL]

This folder structure is the place to link my own project up to.

[image: Final folder structure]

**Linking in your own project**

In your own project of VS Studio (I'm on VS 2008) you have to modify your project properties to include the include files:

[image: Adding include files]

And you have to modify your project properties to include the library files for linking:

[image]

Comment: Does bin sub-folder only have itkTestDriver.exe file?

Comment: How to link it to my project? 
I have problem with linking itk to my project. This is my question's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739488/running-helloworld-example-of-itk-in-visual-studio-2013
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: In your project, you add the path to the "include" folder in the project properties "C++->Gerneral->Additional Include Directories", and you add the path to the "lib" folder in the project properties "Linker->General->Additional Library Directories". Note that you need to do that for Debug/Release separately!

Comment: I've amended the answer above to clarify this.