# Running HelloWorld example of itk in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, itk, external-dependencies

I have installed itk on my system using the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285254/llinking-itk-insight-toolkit-to-c-vs2008-solution-without-using-cmake).

So, I have bin, include, lib, share sub-folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\ITK.

(Small question : does bin sub-folder only have "itkTestDriver.exe" file?)

Now, I am trying to run HelloWorld example. I have created a project which consists of HelloWorld.cpp.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "itkImage.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {    typedef itk::Image< unsigned short, 3 > ImageType;

    ImageType::Pointer image = ImageType::New();

    std::cout << "ITK Hello World !" << std::endl;  std::cin;

    return 0; }
```

I have never used external libraries, so I searched on internet and I did the followings :

- In Projects->properties->linker->input->additional dependencies : 
  kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\ITK\lib\ITKCommon-4.6.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
- Projects->properties->linker->general->additional library directories : C:\Program Files (x86)\ITK\include\

However, I still have problem and I can not build my program due to fatal error of not finding a header file.

I have also tried to copy all of the header files in ITK\include\ to my project's directory, but I still have the same error for other files.

I would be thankful if someone kindly help me with this problem.

---

UPDATE:

I did the followings:

- Projects->properties->linker->input->additional dependencies : I added C:\Program Files (x86)\ITK\lib*.lib;
- Projects->properties-> C/C++-> additional include directories : I added C:\Program Files (x86)\ITK\include\ITK-4.6;

Then, I was getting this error:

> Error 1   error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters
>   that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the
>   passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use
>   -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' i:\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xutility  2132    1   ConsoleApplication1

I fixed it by disabling the warning:

- In "Projects->properties-> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Specific Warnings ->"  I added "4996".

Comment: You have fixed linker errors, but first you need to add ITK h-files directory to the list of additional include directories for C++ compiler.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add "C:\Program Files (x86)\ITK\include\ITK-4.6\" to "Projects->properties->linker->input->additional dependencies"?
I did that, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I highly recommend against this path. Use CMake to generate your Visual Studio applications instead. In the long run it will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Projects->Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories